# Spark Cassandra - Get row with latest timestamp per day

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a cassandra table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CategoryDetails (
name text,
id text,
ts timestamp,
price double,
category text,
PRIMARY KEY ((name, id), ts, price, category))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC, price DESC);
```

I want to be able to query this table using spark-cassandra connector in such a way that I get rows with latest timestamp per day with (name, id, category) as the key. For example, for the below table

```
  Name     id     price    category          ts
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 ("kids", "1234", "3.99", "Toys", "2017-07-11 09:00:52"),
 ("kids", "1234", "3.99", "Toys", "2017-07-11 08:00:52"),
 ("kids", "1234", "4.99", "Toys", "2017-07-11 07:00:52"),
 ("kids", "1234", "5.99", "Toys", "2017-07-12 12:00:52")
```

The desired result would be, the latest record from each day per (name, id, category)

```
 Name     id     price    category          ts
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 ("kids", "1234", "3.99", "Toys", "2017-07-11 09:00:52"),
 ("kids", "1234", "5.99", "Toys", "2017-07-12 12:00:52")
```

So far I have a query and I am doing some map (to get just the date from the timestamp as one of the keys) and reduceByKey (by selecting just the latest ts per day) on them which is causing data to shuffle and is not preserving the Cassandra partitioner. (I can update the code if necessary).

My question, is there a way I could get the desired data at the query level itself?